# in Excel Range copy, How can I copy without changing the active sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

There're several tabs in a workbook(Excel file).
I want to get a copy from other tabs not in active.
When I try this, the control changes from current tab to source tab, so the monitor blinks shortly due to the activation changes by VBA codes.
I'd like to know how to write codes for copying of a range in other tabs without changing active tab.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to superuser, please share your VBA code with us.

Comment: Do you mean worksheets instead of tabs?

Answer (score 1):

In your VBA sub or function you can use the [Application.ScreenUpdating Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221605%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to do what you are asking. This is especially useful for long complex codes and can improve performance.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
*Your code*
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```